# Insert info into an HTTP header

Tags: java, rest, http-headers

I’m trying to add some data to the http header that comes back from a RESTful web service call. Is it possible to use JAX-RS or something else to add data to the response header?

Example of my method:

```
@GET

@Path("getAssets")

public List<Asset> getAssets(@QueryParam("page") @DefaultValue("1") String  page,

                 @QueryParam("page_size") @DefaultValue(UNLIMITED) String  pageSize) throws Exception
{
  stuff…
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is something I don't understand in your question ... you want to add something to the headers of your HTTP *response* ? Is it that ? Because your question seems to suggest that you want to modify the input http header before to process it. Can you be more clear on which http header you want to change and when ?

Answer (score 0):

Using something such as Spring's MVC controller, you can easily get and set response headers as in the below example. A list of common headers can be found here [Wikipedia - Common Headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers)

...

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String myGetMethod(@PathVariable string owner, @PathVariable string pet, HttpServletResponse response) {

response.setContentType("text/html");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=fufu.png");

}
...